# Passing vim functions to vim's inbuilt python

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to set a python variable in vim using vimscript output. The following code is causing the issue:

```
 python os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = split(expand("%:p:h"), "\/")[4].'.settings'
```

The issue is that i am running a line of python code, but want everything after the "=" sign to be evaluated by vim, as I want to assign the value of the `:split(expand("%:p:h"), "\/")[4].'.settings'` vim command to the python variable os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import vim
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = \
    vim.eval("""expand("%:p:h")""").split('/')[4] + '.settings'
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!

To insert this into a .vimrc, the following lines are what do it.

`python import vim` <NEW-LINE>
`python os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = vim.eval("""split(expand("%:p:h"), "\/")[4].'.settings'""")`